# Java http get request slower than postman get request

Tags: java, postman, get-request

I'm trying to send a get request in order to get a website content.
When I'm using Postman it takes about 70-100 ms, but when I use the following code:

```
String getUrl = "someUrl";

URL obj = new URL(getUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// optional default is GET
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

//add request header
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

response.toString();
```

it takes about 3-4 seconds.

Any idea how to get my code work as fast as Postman?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try disabling the use of the Http Agent?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a workaround for the while loop. Maybe that is your bottleneck. What are you even getting from your URL? Json object or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

```
HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(someUri, String.class)
    .responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer())
    .addDefaultHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
    .build();

public void send(){
   String response = httpRequest.execute().get();
}
```

I higly recomend read documentation before use.